# Why do I get different clicks and impression numbers on my domain & prefix properties?

Tags: google-search-console

I've got for my website (example.com) domain property on GSC.
While doing search results report I'm filtering `page=URL` Containing `example.com/pt-br/news` and get the clicks & impressions.

In addition, I have a prefix property for `example.com/pt-br/news`, but there I'm seeing more clicks and impressions for the same time period.

The weird thing is that on the pages list, I'm seeing the same pages of both cases, but with different clicks and impressions number.